# What defines WI-FI?

Tags: ieee-802.11, lan, wan

I don’t quite understand what exactly WI-FI is (regarding to the computer network theory). There are many different definitions of this term. Somewhere it's written that it's a wireless LAN [technology](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/wireless/what-is-wifi.html#:%7E:text=Wi%2DFi%20is%20a%20wireless%20networking%20technology), somewhere it's a wireless LAN [protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi#:%7E:text=Wi%2DFi%20(/%CB%88wa%C9%AAfa%C9%AA/)%5B1%5D%5Ba%5D%20is%20a%20family%20of%20wireless%20network%20protocols), and somewhere it's a wireless LAN itself.

And secondly, there're many different LAN technologies: Blutooth, NFC... What exactly defines WI-FI among these ones? IEEE 802.11? Router, modem?

And one more question: if WI-FI is a wireless LAN technology/protocol, then why is WI-FI accessing  to the Internet (WAN)? As far as I understand, local network doesn't have access to the global network. All information exchange happens within the local network, not beyond its borders. Or now "local" and "global" terms become something vague?

Answer (score 2):

Wi-Fi is a trademark of the [Wi-Fi alliance](https://www.wi-fi.org/).  They define what the different types of Wi-Fi mean. But it has also become a common term for general wireless networking. So as commonly used, it's a bit of a vague term.

I think it is safe to say that for any equipment or technology that is based on the 802.11 protocols, would generally be considered Wi-Fi.  That distinguishes it from other wireless technologies such as Bluetooth, *etc.*

> if WI-FI is a wireless LAN technology/protocol, then why is WI-FI accessing to the Internet (WAN)?

I'm not sure I understand your question.  Wi-Fi as generally used, means a wireless LAN technology.